# Proliant ML350 Won't Load Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP Proliant ML350 G4 running Windows 2003 Server Std Edition that will not load Windows on boot.

It gave me a BSOD while running a recent Windows update and has not been able to boot since. The BSOD was a generic error, "Hardware Fault. Contact vendor."

I am not getting any errors when the machine boots - it just hangs with a black screen when Windows starts to load. The machine will not boot into safe mode either - it gets stuck after beginning to load drivers.

When trying to load the Windows recovery console I get the message that Windows cannot find any hard disks on the machine, despite having to load the driver for my storage controller.

The HP Smart Start diagnostics finds no problems with my hard disks nor anything else.

What should I try next? Mainly, I just want to be able to pull the data off my hard disks.

Comment: You can try loading a Linux live boot CD and see if it will mount the drives and recover the data from that.

Comment: have you tried contacting the vendor?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to load "last known good"?  Have seen a hardware update get added to Critical Updates and then the system does not boot.

Comment: No, attempting to load the "last known good" exhibits the same behavior.